# base64 decoding histogram image

Tags: java, base64, histogram, image-conversion

I have one analyzer that sends me base64 of histogram of blood cells (you can see here https://i.imgur.com/QlIhc6O.png) , when i decode base64 string and get image directly from it , image cant be uploaded.Example of base64 :

```
AAAADiM9XXCAi5CUlpKLgHduZmBVS0A4MzAuKychHRoZGRkXFBEPDw4ODgwKCggICgoLCws==
```

I tried that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String base64Histogram = "AAAADiM9XXCAi5CUlpKLgHduZmBVS0A4MzAuKychHRoZGRkXFBEPDw4ODgwKCggICgoLCwsLCwwPERQZHiMpAA==";

            try {
                    // Decode Base64 string
                    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Histogram);

                    // Save the decoded binary data to an image file
                    String outputFilePath = "histogram.png";//also tried jpg format
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
                    outputStream.write(decodedBytes);
                    outputStream.close();

                    System.out.println("Histogram image saved as: " + outputFilePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

}
result is that image saved but not loaded , it cant be seen

Comment: That is definitely not an image.  It's only 64 bytes long.  It looks like it the raw histogram bin values from that PLT image, one bin per byte.

Comment: can u understand more clearly or any link that can help me , thanks in advance

Comment: They are giving you the numbers they plotted, not the image of the plot.  The numbers here start out 0, 0, 0, 14, 35, 61, 93, 112, 128, 139,...  If you want to see a plot, you will have to create the plot yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show you what you have, here is what I get if I do a base64 decode and then plot the bytes as data points.  I wrote this in Python because it's easier to plot from Python:

```
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inp = 'AAAADiM9XXCAi5CUlpKLgHduZmBVS0A4MzAuKychHRoZGRkXFBEPDw4ODgwKCggICgoLCwsLCwwPERQZHiMpAA=='
x = base64.b64decode(inp)
y = list(x)
plt.plot( y )
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: super , it helps